# How to retrieve all users' data from firestore database except current user, then view the data in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

[1. Users Structure in firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ng02.png)
[2. Information of each user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtOfZ.png)

The two images explain the structure of authenticated users in a firestore database.
What i want is to retrieve all users' data except current user, and store it in a new collection named "Contacts" for current user, So, the track will be (Users-> uId-> Contacts-> document-> first user data...).
Then, make current user access these data and view it inside a recyclerView.
I'm stuck for hours, if anyone can help me.
Thanks..

```
val uId = auth.currentUser?.uid
    firestore.collection("Users").whereNotEqualTo("uId", uId!!).get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            id = document.data["uId"].toString()
            fName = document.data["fullName"].toString()
            fNum = document.data["fullNum"].toString()
            status = document.data["status"].toString()
            img = document.data["image"].toString()
            presence = document.data["presence"].toString()
            val contact = hashMapOf<String, Any>("uId" to id,"fullName" to fName, "fullNum" to fNum,
                "image" to img, "presence" to presence)
            firestore.collection("Contacts").document(uId).collection("rooms").add(contact)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener { Toast.makeText(context, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
```

....................

Comment: Any error with this code?

Comment: @XeauEoan If you found a solution, maybe it will be useful if you'd share that with us by answering your own question.

Comment: @AlexMamo -- I've changed my code sample already to the right one, but forgot to update my screenshot images, Sorry for my late answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for retrieving other users' data, just by changing my  firestore database structure and make it more understandable. The two screenshots above for the old structure. The screenshots below for the new structure... in the second screenshot, i added a collection "Contacts" -> a document "current user ID"
-> a subcollection "rooms" -> a document with "receiver ID" which holds the retrieved data.

[Screenshot for the users' information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAhGg.png)

[Screenshot for rooms related to each user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXgd4.png)

Function addContacts() called first onCreate(), then called every time Users' data updated in changeListener() function. So, our retrieved data remains up-to-date on users' data changed.

```
private fun changeListener(){
    firestore.collection("Users").addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e->
            if (e != null){
                Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e)
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED) {
                    addContacts()
                    Log.d(TAG, "New city: ${dc.document.data}")
                }
            }
        }
}

private fun addContacts(){
    //Adding Contacts
    val uId = auth.currentUser?.uid
    firestore.collection("Users").whereNotEqualTo("uId", uId!!).get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            id = document.data["uId"].toString()
            fName = document.data["fullName"].toString()
            fNum = document.data["fullNum"].toString()
            status = document.data["status"].toString()
            img = document.data["image"].toString()
            presence = document.data["presence"].toString()
            val contact = hashMapOf<String, Any>("uId" to id,"fullName" to fName, "fullNum" to fNum,
                "image" to img, "presence" to presence)
            firestore.collection("Contacts").document(uId).collection("rooms")
                .document(id).set(contact)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }.addOnFailureListener { Toast.makeText(context, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
}
```